# Update site immediately after setting Local Storage

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am making a mern stack application and currently I am trying to switch between the login route and main page depending if you are logged in or not. However, this only works once I refresh the page, is there any way I can make it work without having to refresh the page?

App.js

```
  {!localStorage.getItem('token') ? (
         <Redirect exact from='/' to='/login' />
      ): 
      <>
      <Navbar />
      <Redirect to='/' />


      </>
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reacting to changes in local storage is -at best- a weird approach. In practice, the only way for a component to re-render, is by the props that it receives to change, or by using component state via `useState`.

I'll write this imaginary piece of code to illustrate my point:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

// ...

const LoginPage = _props {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('token'))

  if (token) {
    return <Redirect to='/' />
  }

  // I have no idea how you login your users
  return (
    <div>
      <LoginForm onToken={setToken} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you need component A to react to changes done by component B, where neither of them is a direct child of the other, you will need *global state*.

Global state is similar to component state in that changes on it should trigger a re-render on the component that depends on it. But it is *global*, not local to a particular component.

To achieve this, there are complex solutions like [redux](https://redux.js.org/), but you can implement a very simple version of it using a [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html):

```js
// src/providers/GlobalStateProvider.js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react'

const Context = createContext()

const GlobalStateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [token, doSetToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('token'))

  const setToken = t => {
    doSetToken(t)
    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
  }

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ token, setToken }}>
      {children}
    </Context>
  )
}

export { Context }
export default GlobalStateProvider

// src/App.js
import GlobalStateProvider from './providers/GlobalStateProvider'
// ...
const App = _props => {
  return (
    {/* Any component that is descendant of this one can access the context values, an will re-render if they change */}
    <GlobalStateProvider>
      {/* ... the rest of your components */}
    </GlobalStateProvider>
  )
}
// ...

// your particular component
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { Context } from 'path/to/GlobalStateProvider'

const SomeComponent = _props => {
  // Component will re-render if token changes
  // you can change token from wherever by using `setToken`
  const { token, setToken } = useContext(Context)

  if (token) {
    // do this
  } else {
    // do that
  }
}
```